# Prove that $n^2-4m-2\ne0$ by contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Let $n$ and $m$ be integers. How do I prove that $n^2-4m-2$ is never zero, by contradiction? I have no idea how to start.

Comment: What proof should be "verified" (since you added the tag "proof-verification")?

Answer (score 3):

HINT :

Show that no square is of the form $4m+2$ By considering that it is divisible by 2 and not by 4.

Answer (score 2):

An elementary application of congruences follows. Suppose on the contrary that a solution exists, i.e.
$$n^2=4m+2$$
for some $m,n\in\Bbb Z$. Then, considering the equation modulo 4:

- the left-hand side is either 0 or 1 modulo 4
- the right-hand side is 2 modulo 4

But $0\ne2$ and $1\ne2$, so we always get a contradiction. Hence the equation has no solutions in integers.

Comment: This is not really a proof by contradiction. You just prove the equation cannot have integer roots  because $2$ is not a square  modulo 4. Contradiction is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n^2 = 4m+2$.  $4m+2$ is even, so $n^2$ is even, so $n$ is even, say $n=2k$.  Then $n^2 = 4k^2 = 4m+2$.  Then $2 = 4m-4k^2 = 4(m-k^2)$.  So $2$ is a multiple of $4$. Contradiction.